# Manipulating the DOM of a collection of divs using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

Am working on the frontend part of an application whereby I have
some form inputs (wrapped in divs). Each div has a button called 
Add Beneficiary. Basically when the user clicks on the button, the div 
below it should be displayed (which is hidden by default) and the
sequence continues (each button on a div clicked the div below it
displays).

On the button of each div I have writen some logic whereby on click event
a function called addBeneficiary is triggered. I parse the id of the
button clicked. Next in the function I manipulate the DOM by reaching
out to the parent div and displaying it but the logic does not
work.

~ Kindly assist?

**Markup**

```
<!--Person One-->
<div class="container mg-t-30" id="beneficiary1">
    <div class="row col-11 mx-auto">
        <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label> Category</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label>Family Size</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <button class="float-right btn btn-primary" id="btnBen1" onclick="addBeneficiary(this.id)">Add Beneficiary</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Person Two-->
<div class="container mg-t-30" style="display:none;" id="beneficiary1">
    <div class="row col-11 mx-auto">
        <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label> Category</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label>Family Size</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <button class="float-right btn btn-primary" id="btnBen1" onclick="addBeneficiary(this.id)">Add Beneficiary</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Logic**

```
function addBeneficiary(beneficiary){
    let check = $('#' + beneficiary).parents('div').last().prop('id');
    //console.log(check);

    $("check").css("display", "block");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not working because both parents div id is "beneficiary1". And you can't use same id with multiple tag. It should be unique like beneficiary1, beneficiary2 & so on... And also little bit change into your script.

```
function addBeneficiary(beneficiary){
    let check = $('#' + beneficiary).parents('div').next('div');
    //console.log(check);

    check.css("display", "block");
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y2mva6es/

Comment: **TypeError: $(...).parents(...).sibllings is not a function**  I get this error,,

Comment: Seems not to be working from my side,, Have you tried on Jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks,,. In the actual project I have upto 10 divs,, when I implement your code on the project and click on the button all the 10 divs are opening but I want the single div below to open after each button click..

Comment: ,, Is it possible to remove the same div when another button called **Remove Beneficiary** is clicked as shown in this fiddle **https://jsfiddle.net/mzntrjup/**  Am abit of a beginner in Js

Comment: check for remove and add dynamically upto 10 Beneficiary https://jsfiddle.net/fwvuz68p/ @Martin